# redirect reverse-proxy to SSL depending on origin of request

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have an NGINX server which binds to port 443, provides authentication, and reverse-proxies all SSL requests to a bunch of back-end servers. Another server listens on port 80, but it momentarily does simply leads to a placeholder page. How do I get NGINX to redirect all external requests to the SSL-protected sites, while redirecting all intranet requests to the same sites without SSL? Here is the relevant part of my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  intranet;
allow 10.10.0.0/16;
    #charset koi8-r;
    access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

#######################################
#
# locations on LOCALHOST
#
#######################################         

    location / {
    allow   all;
        root   /data/www;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
##############
# HTTPS server
##############

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;

    ssl_certificate      /srv/ssl/ExternalSite.com.combined.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /srv/ssl/ExternalSite.key;

    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;


    #######################################
    #
    # Reverse proxy blocks
    #
    #######################################         


    #General ExternalSite web site
    location / {
        auth_basic "Please enter userid and password to enter the ExternalSite web site";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/www.ExternalSite.com/.htpasswd;
        proxy_buffers 16 4k;
        proxy_buffer_size 2k;
        proxy_buffering off;   
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_pass http://10.10.10.16:2080;
        }       

    #nagios server 
    location  /nagios  {
        auth_basic "Please enter userid and password to enter the ExternalSite nagios web site";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/www.ExternalSite.com/.htpasswd;
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        proxy_buffers 16 4k;
        proxy_buffer_size 2k;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_pass http://10.10.10.18/nagios;
        }       

    # # munin server
    location  /munin  {
        auth_basic "Please enter userid and password to enter the ExternalSite munin web site";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/www.ExternalSite.com/.htpasswd;
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        proxy_buffers 16 4k;
        proxy_buffer_size 2k;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_pass http://10.10.10.18/munin;
        }       
    #######################################
    #
    # End of Reverse proxy blocks
    #
    #######################################         
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To split Intranet and external requests, create another server section and modify the listen instruction to include corresponding interface. 
I.e., if your Intranet interface is 10.10.10.1 and public IP is 54.200.200.200, for Intranet you would do:
listen 10.10.10.1:80

And for external requests:
listen 54.200.200.200:80

Then to redirect to ssl, use the nginx return statement to the same server but with https.

**Update: sample Nginx configuration schema (as per comments):**

```
#######################################
#
# Intranet server
#
#######################################         
server {
    listen       10.10.10.1:80 default_server;
    server_name  intranet;
    allow 10.10.0.0/16;
    deny all;
    # server configuration with all locations, proxy_passes, etc.
}

#######################################
#
# Internet server, redirecting to ssl
#
#######################################         
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.yourdomain.com;

    location / {
      return https://www.yourdomain.com$request_uri;
    }
}
##############
# HTTPS server
##############

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  www.yourdomain.com;
    # server configuration with all locations, proxy_passes, etc.
}
```

Comment: I don't know why somebody downgraded this, but this is exactly what you have to do. Don't listen on the catchall address, but use separate listeners for the internal and external networks and configure them in their own section.

Comment: Thank you talyyweb and Steffen. You are very helpful and I really appreciate you taking time for me. May I prevail on you and ask you whether you would be so kind and provide a few lines showing how I would fix my server? It would be great for me, and may enhance the general usefulness of your answer for others as well.

Comment: I should add that the external IP is dynamic. Hence I cannot ask the server to listen to a specific IP. Can I somehow configure it to listen to any IP address except 10.10.0.0/16? Alternatively I could of course have it listen to the FQDN name of the server which is of course fixed.

Comment: Added a sample configuration schema that should work for your case. Didn't have a chance to test it though. Also, you may find this article useful: [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)

Comment: Thank you. Do I understand you right that your configuration proposal requires that all proxy_passes, locations, etc. be identically replicated on both the intranet server and the https server? Or is there a way to consolidate them?

Comment: You may (should) use the upstream directives and the named location directives (with @name) to avoid repeating configuration blocks. Also you may consider moving some proxy directives (such as proxy_set_header) to a higher level than location, such as server or even http. However, for the initial start/testing I would just use copy-paste of the existing configuration. Then once it works, refactor it from there.